# distribution plot of feature importances

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, random-forest

I have done a feature selection in my data frame based on this:
https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-using-random-forest-26d7b747597f

on part 7, for ploting distrubution of importance, provides this code:

```
pd.series(sel.estimator_,feature_importances_,.ravel()).hist()
```

which I think it should be like this to not have syntax error:

```
pd.series(sel.estimator_,feature_importances_.ravel()).hist()
```

and I received this error:

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'

and I think estimator_ and feature_importances_ are not defined too.
Is there any way to debug this line of code?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pd.Series(sel.estimator_.feature_importances_.ravel()).hist()
```

It is "Series" not "series"

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.hist.html

### Plotting Feature importance

```
importances = sel.estimator_.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
# X is the train data used to fit the model 
plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(range(X.shape[1]), importances[indices],
       color="r", align="center")
plt.xticks(range(X.shape[1]), indices)
plt.xlim([-1, X.shape[1]])
plt.show()
```

This should render a bar graph like below where x-axis is the feature indexes and y axis is the feature importance. The features are sorted in the order of importance.
[image]

Comment: NameError: name 'feature_importances_' is not defined

Comment: @CFD Normally  feature_importances_ is a member of tree/forest based classifiers. Check if it is member of sel in your case i.e sel.feature_importances_

Comment: It isn't. with sel.feature_importances_ is received this error: AttributeError: 'SelectFromModel' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_

Comment: @CFD I have corrected it now, the website from where you based your code did very bad proof reading :( Dont forget to use plt.show() to render the histogram

Comment: Thanks it worked. But this plot doesn't show anything special!  (updated the question with a picture of plot)